# Pinyinated 'm' with four tone marks?

Tags: pinyin

I know 'm' is a pinyin pronunciation. Looking through my dictionaries I've seen it listed in first, second and fourth tones. I can't seem to find the correct accented lower-case 'm's anywhere though...

Tone marks are as follows:

- 1st tone = ˉ (macron)
- 2nd tone = ˊ (acute accent)
- 3rd tone = ˇ (caron/háček)
- 4th tone = ˋ (grave accent)

So basically what I'm asking is where can I find:

- lower case m with macron
- lower case m with acute
- lower case m with caron/háček
- lower case m with grave

anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tones are only applied to wovels. There are no tones associated with consonant "m", so you have to assume a prefix wovel like "e" before the "m". Unicode-wise, you can get an accented ḿ but no other variants.

Yes, you see accented "m" in dictionaries, but they are outside pinyin, and also outside unicode.

Comment: 汉语大辞典 lists 呒 as m1 / 唔 as m2

Other places list 呣 as m4 (and a lot of other tones too actually).

Comment: Accented m is clearly not 'outside Unicode' since it can be represented using combining characters: m̀

Comment: Using combining diacritical marks, yes: m̆m̅ḿm̀.

Answer (score 2):

You can find pinyin for 唔 typed as ḿ and m̀ at en.wiktionary.org and I'm sure they have other examples.  I did not look into how they did it -- is it correct for your purposes?  I know nothing about Unicode.  I suppose if you wanted a LaTeX solution that would be easy.

Comment: Here's a first tone: m̄